# How to filter using regex in ng-table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I'm using ng-table how can I search using regex instead of string?

Comment: http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-customize-algorithm

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom filterComparator in ngTableParams:

```
$scope.tableParams = new this.ngTableParams({}, {
    filterOptions: {
        filterComparator: function(actual, expected) {
            return typeof actual == 'string' && actual.match(new RegExp(expected, 'i'));
        }
    }
  });
```

Comment: You ask and answer at the same time??

Comment: @LucasCosta http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question